# Using ggplot function in R error : could not find function ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have installed ggplot and ggplot2 and their dependencies, but I cannot use the function `ggplot`; whenever I try to use it I get

> Error in ggplot ... could not find function "ggplot"

Comment: I don't know where you found a copy of `ggplot`, since it's no longer available on CRAN. `ggplot2` has completely replaced it.

Comment: I would reopen. I think gsk's answer is probably the right one and its definitely a FAQ even if it's not in the FAQ.

Comment: @DWin: yes it is, see FAQ 7.30 ...

Comment: @DWin : it is the right answer, so no more answers needed. These kind of questions best disappear into oblivion.

Comment: @Joris Meys: I guess you changed your mind on that point? (Since you posted a basically an identical question later.)

Comment: @DWin : yeah... Actually, I first thought of editing this one to make it a whole lot more general (basically cutting out the ggplot and replacing it with dots), but then again, gsk3 would have to rewrite his answer. So that's why I made that almost identical question.

Answer (score 57):

Try:

```
library(ggplot2)
```

Even after installing a package, you have to load a package each time you load R.

This question is answered comprehensively in the r-faq:

[Error: could not find function ... in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

Comment: Agree that's the most common newbie mistake that results in that error message.

Comment: after adding `library(ggplot2)` as above, I can use `ggplot` now, thx