# R - could not find function 'melt()'

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error: could not find function … in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

I find various references to the function `melt()`, actually `melt.data.frame()` in stackoverflow for R. But when I call it in R, it gives me

```
Error: could not find function "melt"
```

How do I load that function so I can call it?

Comment: please explain the question completely

Comment: you need to `install.packages("reshape"); library(reshape)`

Comment: You could have found the answer by searching via [rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753%3Aboaz1reyxd4&q=melt&sa=Search+functions%2C+lists%2C+and+more&cof=FORID%3A11).

Comment: or `install.packages("sos"); library("sos"); findFn("melt.data.frame")` (but there's a recursion problem here, since you have to know how to install and load the `sos` package in order to use it to search for `melt.data.frame` ...

Comment: It's also the first Google hit for "melt cran"

Comment: Not duplicate at all. The question isn't "how to solve could not find function errors", but "where is `melt()`".

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `melt` function is to be found in the [`reshape`](http://had.co.nz/reshape/) package.

If you do not have that package installed, then you will need to install it with `install.packages("reshape")` before you can use it. Then, when the package is installed, make it available with `library(reshape)`. At which point you are good to go!

Update 2018: The package in R 3.6.1. is now called [`reshape2`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/reshape2/versions/1.4.3).

The `reshape2` notes also say:

> `reshape2` is retired: only changes necessary to keep it on CRAN will
>   be made. We recommend using [`tidyr`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/)
>   instead.

`tidyr` does not contain the `melt` function.

Comment: @Mr.T Please make an edit to the answer in that case