# Package IQCC in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error: could not find function … in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

I have entered this example:

```
mu <- c(5.682, 88.22)
Sigma <- symMatrix(c(3.770, -5.495, 13.53), 2)
datum <- data.1(20, 10, mu, Sigma)
estat <- stats(datum, 20, 10, 2)
datum2 <- data.2(estat, 10, p = 2)
T2II <- T2.2(datum2, estat, 10)

#Not showing the phase I data set.
cchart.T2.2(T2II, 20, 10, 1, 25, 2)
datum3 <- data.2(estat, 10, p = 2)
add.data(datum3, estat, T2II, 10, 2)

#Showing the phase I data set.
cchart.T2.2(T2II, 20, 10, 1, 25, 2, datum = datum)
datum3 <- data.2(estat, 10, p = 2)
add.data(datum3, estat, T2II, 10, 2, 20)
```

and I have dowloaded package IQCC but i have this message of error

```
> mu <- c(5.682, 88.22)
> Sigma <- symMatrix(c(3.770, -5.495, 13.53), 2)
Erreur : impossible de trouver la fonction "symMatrix"  (impossible to find the function..)
> datum <- data.1(20, 10, mu, Sigma)
Erreur : impossible de trouver la fonction "data.1"
> estat <- stats(datum, 20, 10, 2)
Erreur : impossible de trouver la fonction "stats"
> datum2 <- data.2(estat, 10, p = 2)
Erreur : impossible de trouver la fonction "data.2"
> T2II <- T2.2(datum2, estat, 10)
Erreur : impossible de trouver la fonction "T2.2"
> #Not showing the phase I data set.
> cchart.T2.2(T2II, 20, 10, 1, 25, 2)
Erreur : impossible de trouver la fonction "cchart.T2.2"
> datum3 <- data.2(estat, 10, p = 2)
Erreur : impossible de trouver la fonction "data.2"
> add.data(datum3, estat, T2II, 10, 2)
Erreur : impossible de trouver la fonction "add.data"
> #Showing the phase I data set.
> cchart.T2.2(T2II, 20, 10, 1, 25, 2, datum = datum)
Erreur : impossible de trouver la fonction "cchart.T2.2"
> datum3 <- data.2(estat, 10, p = 2)
Erreur : impossible de trouver la fonction "data.2"
> update.packages(ask='graphics')
```

For the first function `symMatrix`, I have downloaded (MiscTools) the same problem still present, impossible to find the function. Does anyone know a solution?