# Error: could not find function in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error: could not find function … in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

Well, I am new to the concept of `rattle` (data mining package in R), and while I have installed `rattle` but when I give `rattle()`, it gives me the following error

```
> rattle()
Error in rattle() : could not find function "gtkBuilderNew"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you read error message?

`Error in rattle() : could not find function "gtkBuilderNew"`

The package `RGtk2` is required to display the Rattle GUI. It does not appear to be installed. This package (and its dependencies) can be installed using the following R command:

```
install.packages('RGtk2')
```

Comment: hi ymn ,Well basically i have installed the RGtk2 package but still i am getting this error or warning

Comment: what say `rattleInfo()`?

Comment: RattleInfo() give me 29 packages update and that followed by the following statement         Update the packages with either of the following commands:

  > install.packages(c("foreign", "nnet"))

  > install.packages(rattleInfo())

Alternatively update all installed packages:

> update.packages()

Comment: i am using linux Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Try to install `libgtk2.0-dev` and `libxml2-dev` packages.

Comment: have you done `library(RGtk2)`?

Comment: When i give library(RGtk2)
that package is not installed while i have that package in my download_packages in R

now when i am trying install.packages('RGtk2')
it gives me the following 

* installing *source* package ‘RGtk2’ ...
** package ‘RGtk2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for INTROSPECTION... no
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: GTK version 2.8.0 required
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RGtk2’

What to do

Comment: @ymn is correct - Rgtk2 is a source package, so requires the -dev package to compile it. XML (also needed for rattle) is the same.