# Trying to create an AICc table but receiving aictab error message

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial

I'm trying to create an AICc table for a number of multinomial logistic regression models. However, when I try to run the line:

```
                    aictab(cand.set = Cand.mod, modnames = Modnames)
```

I get the error message:

```
             Error in print(aictab(cand.set = Cand.models, modnames = Modnames)) : 
                                 could not find function "aictab"
```

The script I am using is:

```
                     install.packages("AICcmodavg")

                     dd$reaction2 <- relevel(dd$reaction, ref="nr") 

                     Cand.mod<-list()

                     Cand.mod[[1]]<-multinom(reaction2~ camera + light, data = dd)

                     Cand.mod[[2]]<-multinom(reaction2~ camera + gender, data = dd)

                     Modnames <-c("fm1", "fm2", "fm3")

                     aictab(cand.set = Cand.mod, modnames = Modnames)

                     evidence(aictab(cand.set = Cand.mod, modnames = Modnames))

                confset(cand.set = Cand.mod, modnames = Modnames, method= "raw")
```

I'm just wondering if anyone has any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: What happens if you add `library(AICcmodavg)` after `install.packages("AICcmodavg")`?

Comment: Oh my god you genius, that worked! Thanks a million!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: could not find function ... in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)