# R error: could not find function

Tags: r

I'm using the code: 
`setDT(data)[ ,.SD[which.min(Julian_Day)],.(species,year)]` to make a subset of my data set and have to include the `library(data.table)` which I made sure to install but I keep getting and error message:

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "."

I've used this before in the past with no problem so I'm not sure what's going on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the `.` has only been a recent addition - are you using the most up-to-date development version of `data.table` ?

Comment: I have 1.9.2 installed and the repository version is 1.9.2 if that's what you mean

Comment: Current version for github is 1.9.4 furthermore that repos says it has been for 6 months   "v1.9.4 on CRAN, released 2nd Oct 2014."

Comment: How can I get the newest version? I've just been going to install packages at the top and loading whatever they suggest...

Comment: `devtools::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)`

Comment: Trying the above I got: ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’
* removing ‘/Users/natalyamaitz/Library/R/3.1/library/data.table’
Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: Great answers for the duplicate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r