# Rcpp package cannot find function

Tags: r, rcpp

I have written my first R package using `Rcpp`; the package is a simple utility to read in binary data files written by the application TransCAD. When I build the package in Rstudio, everything runs correctly.

I pushed my work to [GitHub](https://github.com/gregmacfarlane/tcadr), and installed it from a different R session. Everything is as it should be.

```
devtools::install_github("gregmacfarlane/tcadr")

Downloading github repo gregmacfarlane/tcadr@master
Installing tcadr
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  '/private/var/folders/wr/zlxhfd3d3591b4b9zgq4c5xr0000gn/T/Rtmpa2Xoyi/devtools3ca351cdd2e/gregmacfarlane-tcadr-65fc460'  \
  --library='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library'  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘tcadr’ ...
** libs
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o tcadr.so RcppExports.o get_df_from_binary.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcadr/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (tcadr)
```

But when I try to run my package's primary R function, it cannot find the c++ function I wrote.

```
library(tcadr)
df <- read_tcad_bin(dir, file)
Error in as.data.frame(get_df_from_binary(bin_file, dcb$name, dcb$type,  : 
  could not find function "get_df_from_binary"
```

I have checked that the [rcpp export] function was compiled properly by the Rstudio build. Are there other things I ought to check also?

**mwe** the package `data/` folder has an example dataset that you can test on if needed.

---

#### Update

I think this should not be a new question, but may rather help to indicate what the problem is.

On three different computers (two OS X 10.10.3, one Windows 7) the following happens:

- If I install the package with `devtools::install_github()`, the R function is unable to find the C function.
- If I clone the repository from github and build it inside RStudio, the library works flawlessly.

As per the comment on compilers below, it seems RStudio on Mac uses `gcc`, but in the console uses `clang`. Windows uses `g++` in both.

Comment: I've seen [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24693168/843419) and I'm passing the correct number of arguments.

Comment: You committed object files and the shared library. Don't do that.

Comment: As a side note, this didn't build for me (g++ 4.8.3), even after forking your repo and removing `get_df_from_binary.o` and `tcadr.so`. I noticed you're using clang, so if you intend to distribute this package you might want to look into that.

Comment: Ditto -- nrussell and I did you the same public service.  See below for details.

Comment: You guys are heroes. Looking at it now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the set of errors I am getting under Ubuntu 14.10:

```
/tmp$ cat /tmp/tcadr.Rcheck/00install.out
* installing *source* package ‘tcadr’ ...
** libs
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -c get_df_from_binary.cpp -o get_df_from_binary.o
get_df_from_binary.cpp: In function ‘Rcpp::List get_df_from_binary(Rcpp::String, Rcpp::CharacterVector, Rcpp::CharacterVector, Rcpp::NumericVector, Rcpp::NumericVector, int)’:
get_df_from_binary.cpp:31:53: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_fstream<char>::open(Rcpp::String&, std::_Ios_Openmode)’
   bf.open(bin_file, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
                                                     ^
get_df_from_binary.cpp:31:53: note: candidate is:
In file included from get_df_from_binary.cpp:4:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/fstream:889:7: note: void std::basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
       open(const char* __s,
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/fstream:889:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Rcpp::String’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:142: recipe for target 'get_df_from_binary.o' failed
make: *** [get_df_from_binary.o] Error 1
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -c get_df_from_binary.cpp -o get_df_from_binary.o
get_df_from_binary.cpp: In function ‘Rcpp::List get_df_from_binary(Rcpp::String, Rcpp::CharacterVector, Rcpp::CharacterVector, Rcpp::NumericVector, Rcpp::NumericVector, int)’:
get_df_from_binary.cpp:31:53: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_fstream<char>::open(Rcpp::String&, std::_Ios_Openmode)’
   bf.open(bin_file, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
                                                     ^
get_df_from_binary.cpp:31:53: note: candidate is:
In file included from get_df_from_binary.cpp:4:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/fstream:889:7: note: void std::basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
       open(const char* __s,
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/fstream:889:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Rcpp::String’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:142: recipe for target 'get_df_from_binary.o' failed
make: *** [get_df_from_binary.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tcadr’
* removing ‘/tmp/tcadr.Rcheck/tcadr’
/tmp$
```

I think you need to fix a few things.

*Edit:* It appears to at least compile if you do this instead:

```
diff --git a/src/get_df_from_binary.cpp b/src/get_df_from_binary.cpp
index 13d1b4a..15cd340 100644
--- a/src/get_df_from_binary.cpp
+++ b/src/get_df_from_binary.cpp
@@ -28,7 +28,7 @@ List get_df_from_binary(

   // Open the binary data file and make sure it exists
   std::fstream bf;
-  bf.open(bin_file, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
+  bf.open(bin_file.get_cstring(), ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
   if(!bf.is_open()){
     throw std::range_error("could not open binary file");
   }
```