# How to find the package name in R for a specific function?

Tags: r

I want to use `computeEstimate()` function. But since the specific package is not installed in my R, I am getting error:

> could not find function "computeEstimate"

Can you please let me know which package I should install to get this function? Also - how do I find a package for a specific function in R?

Comment: you might want to check that `computeEstimate` isn't a function someone wrote outside of a package.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r) you can find a lot of ways to find a function

Answer (score 19):

Install the package sos first, then:

```
require("sos")
findFn("computeEstimate")
```

This function searches the help pages of packages covered by the RSiteSearch archives (which includes all packages on CRAN).

Although for your example, it did not find a package.

But for example

```
findFn('multiply',maxPages = 1)
```

works fine. Are you sure the function exists somewhere?

Comment: Another way could be to search for the function on [rdocumentation.org](http://rdocumentation.org).

Comment: Thanks. But when I try findFn('max',maxPages=1) getting warning messages as 'Too many documents hit.  Ignored'. Can you please tell me how to get rid off.

Comment: From the documentation:
    # Finds too many matches to process;
    # reports Inf matches but returns none.
    # When this happens, use a more restrictive search