# Which package or packages include the function "polyc"?

Tags: r

When trying to perform polychoric analysis on items from a questionnaire, I get the message "could not find function "polyc", even with the "psych" and "polycor" packages. Is there any way to solve this inconvenience? My gratitude in advance.

Comment: Without any code it is hard to help you. What might be happening is that there is conflict, did you try psych::polychoric?

Comment: There is no `polyc` function in either of those packages. Do you mean `polychor` function from the `polycor` package?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
install.packages("sos")
require("sos")
findFn("polyc")
```

Related: 
[How to find the package name in R for a specific function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397193/how-to-find-the-package-name-in-r-for-a-specific-function)