# Error: could not find function "dbConnect"

Tags: r

I'm working through [the following post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/R/116157/). When I run the code below I get the following error.

```
conn = dbConnect('SqlServer', url=url)

Error: could not find function "dbConnect"
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm still pretty new to R.

Comment: possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r

Comment: The "following post" need a registration. I skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing an import.
Try to add/run

```
install.packages("RSQLServer")

library("RSQLServer")
```

Comment: This is right, just delete the semicolon at the end :)