# R can't find function after installing package

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the function `isdigit` but R can't find it, even after I installed the **qmrparser** package and submitted the code `library(qmrparser)`.

(I'm brand new to R so please explain like I'm 5!)

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I did load it.

Comment: I had marked this as a duplicate, then changed my mind.  Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r.  There's a lot of good information there that might help you.

Comment: @RichardScriven I marked it as off topic since it's just a typo as it should be isDigit instead.

Comment: Either a typo, or a more conceptual 'case does not matter' misunderstanding.

Comment: Yep - I didn't realize that the D needed to be capitalized. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 library(qmrparser)
```

to load / attach the package.  Failing that, try

```
 qmrparser::isdigit()
```

to call it up explicitly using the `::` operator along with the package name.

You can have *thousands* of packages installed, so installed does not automate loading (though you can arrange for that, but that is a different topic).

*Edit:* And if the function is not accessible even after loading try the 'triple-:' operator to access non-exported sysmbols:

```
 qmrparser:::isdigit()
```

*Edit 2:* Your premise was wrong as the function is called [isDigit](https://github.com/cran/qmrparser/blob/master/R/isDigit.R) with a capital-D.  So you have to type

```
 isDigit()
```

which will get you the function as it is [exported via NAMESPACE](https://github.com/cran/qmrparser/blob/master/NAMESPACE).