# In text2vec package in R, could not find function "create_vocab_corpus"

Tags: r, text2vec

I was trying to understand the `text2vec` package from http://dsnotes.com/articles/text2vec
but at the following step:

Now we can costruct DTM. Again, since all functions related to corpus construction have streaming API, we have to create iterator and provide it to create_vocab_corpus function:

```
it <- itoken(movie_review[['review']], preprocess_function = tolower,
             tokenizer = word_tokenizer, chunks_number = 10, progessbar = F)
corpus <- create_vocab_corpus(it, vocabulary = vocab)
```

This code throws an error:

> Error: could not find function "create_vocab_corpus"

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see tutorial for latest version (0.3): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/text2vec/vignettes/text-vectorization.html . There were some API breaks in v 0.3.