# How to reduce geom_text overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataset contains > 500 observations of match activities performed by individual athletes at different locations and recorded over the duration of a soccer match. An example of my dataset is below, where each symbol refers to a match activity. For example, `KE` is Kick Effective, recorded at 1 minute in the `Defense`.

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(Symbol = c('KE', 'TE', 'TE', 'TI',
                              'KE', 'KE', 'H', 'H',
                              'GS', 'KE', 'TE', 'H',
                              'KE', 'H', 'H', 'GS'),
                Location = c('Defense', 'Defense', 'Midfield', 'Forward',
                             'Forward', 'Midfield', 'Midfield', 'Defense',
                             'Defense', 'Defense', 'Forward', 'Midfield',
                             'Midfield', 'Defense', 'Defense', 'Midfield'),
                 Time = c(1, 2, 3, 6,
                            15, 16, 16, 20,
                            22, 23, 26, 26,
                            27, 28, 28, 30))
```

I wish to visualise this data, by plotting the match activities over time at each location in `ggplot2`.

```
# Load required package
require(ggplot2)
# Order factors for plotting
df$Location <- factor(df$Location, levels = c("Defense", "Midfield", "Forward"))

    # Plot
    ggplot(df, x = Time, y = Location) +
      geom_text(data=df, 
                aes(x = Time, y = Location, 
                    label = Symbol), size = 4) +
      theme_classic()
```

However, some of the `geom_text` labels overlap one another. I have tried `jitter` but then I lose meaning of where the activity occurs on the soccer pitch. Unfortunately, `check_overlap=TRUE` removes any overlapped symbols. I wish to keep the symbols in the same text direction.

Although the symbols are plotted at the time they occur, I am happy to adjust the time slightly (aware they will no longer perfectly align on the plot) to ensure the `geom_text` symbols are visible. I can do this manually by shifting the `Time` of each overlapped occurrence forward or back, but with such a big dataset this would take a very long time.

A suggestion was to use `ggrepel` and I did this below, although it alters the `geom_text` in the y-axis which is not what I am after.

```
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(df, x = Time, y = Location) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(Time, Location, label = Symbol))
```

Is there a way I can check for overlap and automatically adjust the symbols, to ensure they are visible and still retain meaning on the y-axis? Perhaps one solution could be to find each `Location` and if a `Symbol` is within two minutes of another in the same `Location`, `Time` is adjusted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: may be `x = jitter(Time, 4)`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately there is still overlap.

Comment: See [ggrepel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html).

Comment: The `ggrepel` solution does work but it alters the y-axis and the labels appear offset, which is not what I am after. I would like the labels all on the same line, slightly altered in the x-axis but definitely not in the y.

Comment: use `set.seed()` sequentially and find the value of seed that separates the text when using `jitter`. This will make your graph reproducible. It is a trial and error process.

Comment: Install the devel version of ggrepel from GitHub, then use `direction = "x"`. See [here for direction option in devel](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/blob/master/R/geom-text-repel.R#L87)

Comment: I also see `ggrepel` promising...

Comment: Regarding edit: "Perhaps one solution could be... " then the plot would be misleading, and would face the same problem once we have 3-5 labels on the same "Time" x axis.

Comment: The plot would be misleading and not at the exact time occurrence but it would assist the visual. The number of labels is not the issue but the overlap is.

Answer (score 5):

We could add points, then use `ggrepel` with minimum line length to points from text labels.

```
library(ggrepel) # ggrepel_0.6.5 ggplot2_2.2.1

ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Location, label = Symbol)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(size = 4, min.segment.length = unit(0.1, "lines")) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]
Or we could try and use development version with ["direction"](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/blob/master/R/geom-text-repel.R#L87) argument.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Location, label = Symbol)) +
  geom_text_repel(size = 4, direction = "x") +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: I ran this code: `devtools::install_github("slowkow/ggrepel")` and then your `geom_text_repel` line but I receive the following error: `Error: could not find function "geom_text_repel"`

Comment: @user2716568 See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r) for possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I did get the development package working. Unfortunately this solution is not what I am after - the `geom_point` detracts from the symbols. The symbols are also not aligned on the axis axis, they are jittered which I am not after.

Comment: @user2716568 I haven't tested the devel version, the first solution above should work, points are not jittered, just the text.

Comment: Yes but I do not want a `geom_point` and nor do I want the text jittered. Therefore, the first solution is not ideal.