# Could not find LoadFile() even if a guide says it should exist, am I or the guide wrong? In R

Tags: r, function, ahp

I need to perform an analytic hierarchical process (AHP) on a dataset using R. I have basic understanding of navigation and can follow most guides to perform rudiment analyses. However, I'm not comfortable enough to be sure if I or the guide is wrong.

The guide I've followed is this: https://www.r-bloggers.com/analytic-hierarchy-process-ahp-with-the-ahp-package/.
(I run R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch")

1: I have (successfully) installed and loaded the AHP package using:

```
devtools::install_github("gluc/ahp", build_vignettes = install.packages("data.tree"))
```

2: I have (successfully) set working directory using:

```
setwd("myworkingdirectory")
```

3: I have attempted (PROBLEM) loaded the file to a variable using:

```
myahp <- LoadFile("myAHPfile.txt")
Error: could not find function "LoadFile"
```

3x: As diagnosis I run:

```
getAnywhere("LoadFile")
no object named ‘LoadFile’ was found
```

*For your information: Step 3x is inspired by this SO answer* ([Error: could not find function ... in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r))

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both. The guide refers to an old version of the gap package from github. With the latest version from cran (0.2.11), the function is now called `Load`, and the file format has changed.
If you just want to goof around with the package, I can recommend the online app at [ipub.com](http://ipub.com/apps/ahp/). 
If you insist on following the guide, make sure you get version 0.1.1 from [github](https://github.com/gluc/ahp/releases/tag/0.1.1)