# Error while knitting a LaTeX file: could not find function "as"

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am trying to knit a chunk embedded in a latex file with extension Rnw.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(flexclust)
library(arules)

data(Groceries)

Gr <- Groceries[, itemFrequency(Groceries) > 0.02]
grc <- as(Gr, "matrix")
```

I get this error:

```
#Error in as(Gr, "matrix") could not find function "as"
```

The same commands work perfectly well in R

Any ideas?

Comment: doesn't as() come from the methods-package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r

Comment: Interestingly enough, adding the library(methods) inside the knitr body solved the problem. Kudos to Wimpel and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[When in doubt, try to upgrade your software packages.](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/) If you are using a recent version of R (>= 3.5.0), you should not need to `library(methods)`, because it will be loaded (attached) by default. This problem (`Rscript` does not load **methods**) [has existed in base R for many years](https://yihui.name/en/2017/12/library-methods/) until this year and surprised/confused many users. If you have to use an old version of R, you will need `library(methods)` explicitly.