# sim.data from package imp4p in R

Tags: r

I'm traying use the function sim.data from the package imp4p in R, but when I put the example
`sim.data(nb.pept=10000,nb.miss=6000,pi.mcar=0.2,para=1.5,nb.cond=1,nb.repbio=3,
nb.sample=3,m.c=25,sd.c=2,sd.rb=0.5,sd.r=0.2)`

I get the following mesagge

`Error in sim.data(nb.pept = 10000, nb.miss = 6000, pi.mcar = 0.2, para = 1.5,  : 
  could not find function "sim.data"`

how can I solver this problem?

Comment: you need to `install.packages("imp4p")` and then `library(imp4p)`. It would be good to review how to install and load packages in R

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: could not find function ... in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)