# Remove NAs from SpatialPixelsDataFrame

Tags: r, na, r-sp

I have a SpatialPixelsDataFrame (sp object) for which I wish to remove all pixels containing NA values in the @data slot. I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174798/remove-nas-from-spatial-dataframe) post but the function throws an error. The final result should equally be a SpatialPixelsDataFrame.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(SpatialEco)

m <- raster::raster(ncol=100, nrow=100) # create raster
m[] <- runif(ncell(m))
m[m < 0.2] <- NA # simulate NAs
spdf <- as(m, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame") # transform to SpatialPixelsDataFrame

spdf_new <- sp.na.omit(st_as_sf(spdf), margin = 1)
Warning message
Function is deprecated because stats::na.omit operates on 
  sf class objects
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the `data` slot object will be stored in a matrix. It makes no sense to "remove" NA values from an entry in a grid structure. There's either a value in a location or there is an NA.