# How to solve "find_rtools" error after installing Rtools

Tags: r, rstudio, rtools

Trying to install Rtools 3.4 with R Version 3.5.1 on windows 7 64 bit. When I use find_rtools() in IDE, it says

*Error in find_rtools() : could not find function "find_rtools"*

Already installed devtools. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so here in an answer.

I suppose you did not load the package before using the function. 
Use:

```
library(devtools)
```

Further information:
[Error: could not find function ... in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Whenever we start a new session, I need to load packages again. If this is true, I was missing on this point.