# How can we solve an error? Error in bca(f = ...: could not find function "bca"

Tags: r

I am using "dst" package(page10,11: combination of two mass functions), when I was writing a small example, it runs correctly. But I write a big functions, it occurs this error:

```
Error in bca(f = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  could not find function "bca"
```

my function is:
it goes wrong:

```
library("dst")

x43 <- bca(f=matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
,nrow=23, byrow = TRUE),
m=c(0.02927918,0.03578567,0.01254822,0.04391877,0.06831808,0.06831808,0.05437561,
0.06831808,0.11711670,0.03578566,0.04387215,0.02927918,0.03575976,0.06839579,
0.02927918,0.06839579,0.02927918,0.01585178,0.02396417,0.01953500,0.04405864,0.02927918,0.02927918),
cnames=c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", "i8", "i9", "i10", "i11", "i12", "i13", "i14",
"i15", "i16", "i17", "i18", "i19", "i20", "i21", "i22", "i23"),
infovarnames = "x", varnb = 1)
```

Error:

```
Error in bca(f = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, : could not find function "bca"
```

a small example that runs correctly:

```
require("dst")
# Loading required package: dst

x25 <- bca(f=matrix(c(1,0,1,1),nrow=2, byrow = TRUE),
m=c(0.8,0.2), cnames=c("i1", "i2"),
infovarnames = "x", varnb = 1)

x26 <- bca(f=matrix(c(0,1,1,1),nrow=2, byrow = TRUE),

m=c(0.7,0.3), cnames=c("i1", "i2"),
infovarnames = "x", varnb = 1)

print ("combination of x25 and x26")

# [1] "combination of x25 and x26"
x25x26 <- dsrwon(x25,x26)
nzdsr(x25x26)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will make it much easier for others to help you. The post is not clear.

Comment: thank you dear. i use the info. please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288

Comment: I don't get that error, I get `Error in bca(f = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  Error in input arguments: check your input data.`

Comment: My input data is correct and i checked it 100 times.

Comment: but i donot get result

Answer (score 0):

@user2554330 is right, please check your data again.
In bca function, values in parameter m must add to one, but in your example they do not:

```
m=c(0.02927918,0.03578567,0.01254822,0.04391877,0.06831808,0.06831808,0.05437561, 0.06831808,0.11711670,0.03578566,0.04387215,0.02927918,0.03575976,0.06839579,   0.02927918,0.06839579,0.02927918,0.01585178,0.02396417,0.01953500,0.04405864,0.02927918,0.02927918)
sum(m)
[1] 0.999993
```