# Extract p-value from gam.check in R

Tags: r, p-value, gam

When I run `gam.check(my_spline_gam)`, I get the following output.

```
Method: GCV   Optimizer: magic
Smoothing parameter selection converged after 9 iterations.
The RMS GCV score gradiant at convergence was 4.785628e-06 .
The Hessian was positive definite.
The estimated model rank was 25 (maximum possible: 25)
Model rank =  25 / 25 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

         k'    edf k-index p-value
s(x) 24.000 22.098   0.849    0.06
```

My question is whether I can extract this p-value separately to a table.

Comment: `str(gam.check(my_spline_gam))` somewhere the p-value should be.

Comment: that still gives the same output, whereas I would just want either only the one line of results or just the p-value. thanks!

Comment: please add the result of `dput(gam.check(my_spline_gam))` to your question. Then I can solve it.

Comment: quick look at the code suggests you can use `k.check(yourmodel, subsample = 5000, n.rep = 200)`

Comment: @AndreElrico: this is the output: dput(gam.check(my_spline_gam))

Method: GCV   Optimizer: magic
Smoothing parameter selection converged after 9 iterations.
The RMS GCV score gradiant at convergence was 4.785628e-06 .
The Hessian was positive definite.
The estimated model rank was 25 (maximum possible: 25)
Model rank =  25 / 25 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

         k'    edf k-index p-value
s(x) 24.000 22.098   0.849    0.03
structure(list(mfrow = c(2L, 2L)), .Names = "mfrow")

Comment: @user20650: k.check returns: Error: could not find function "k.check".

Comment: @a_geo ; it is in the [mgcv package](https://github.com/cran/mgcv/blob/master/R/plots.r#L175). I have package `packageVersion("mgcv") ; ‘1.8.25’` . See [could-not-find-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r) for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`capture.output`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.1/topics/capture.output) coupled with a little string manipulation -

```
gam_obj <- capture.output(gam.check(b,pch=19,cex=.3))
gam_tbl <- gam_obj[12:length(gam_obj)]
str_spl = function(x){
  p_value <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
  output_p <- as.numeric(p_value[length(p_value)])
}
p_values <- data.frame(sapply(gam_tbl, str_spl))
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: thx! it didn't work exactly, but an elaboration of this worked fine. The only thing is that ideally I would also like to have the result up until the 3rd decimal.


gam_obj <- capture.output(gam.check(my_spline_gam,pch=19,cex=.3))

gam_tbl <- gam_obj[12:length(gam_obj)]

p_str = unlist(strsplit(gam_tbl, "   ", fixed=TRUE))

p_value = as.numeric(p_str[8])

p_value

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you cannot store the result in an object the normal way. You could use `capture.output` to store the console output in an object, and then subsequently use `str_split` to get the correct value. So for the example in the help file this would be:

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(0)
dat <- gamSim(1,n=200)
b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat)
r <- capture.output(gam.check(b))
p <- strsplit(r[12], " ")[[1]][11]
```

But because the p-value is just a string you wouldn't get the exact p-value this way.

**Edit: [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650)'s answer will give you the proper output:**

```
r <- k.check(b)
r[,'p-value']
```

Comment: thx! k.check seems not to work. is it another package I should import?

Comment: @a_geo Means you need to do `k.check(my_spline_gam)` rather than `gam.check(my_spline_gam)`. P-values are very similar and you should be able to use them.

Comment: @jay.sf ; p-values are the *same*: any differences are due to  the calculation being stochastic. So best to use `set.seed`

Comment: @user20650 Both commands yield slightly different p-values. But I'm with you that we can *consider* both the same due to stochastic calculations within the commands, where' you cannot easily set a seed and obviously `set.seed()` has no effect.

Comment: @jay.sf ; I was about to disagree with you as `gam.check` explicitly calls `k.check` so they should give the same results (and you can use the `seed` as `set.seed(1) ; 
printCoefmat(k.check(b, subsample = 5000, n.rep = 200), digits = 3)`). However, a quick look shows there are other random sample calls used in the earlier plot functions in `gam.check` (not related to the output table), which will move the seed, hence difficult to get the same. But it is the same function doing the work..

Comment: thank you all, but the k.check() does not work for me. Error: could not find function "k.check"

Comment: @a_geo ; `k.check` exits in mgcv (and is actually in `gam.check`). If you can't see the function, or don't have it, it could be because you are using an earlier version of mgcv or R. Can you edit your question with the results of `sessionInfo()`.