# R 3.5.1, could not find function "dbConnect"

Tags: r

```
install.packages("DBI")
install.packages("RSQLite")
install.packages("sqldf")

mydb<-dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),"my-db.sqlite")
```

> Error in dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "PSTAT10-db.sqlite") :    could
>   not find function "dbConnect"

I would be very grateful!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: could not find function ... in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DBI::dbConnect` or `library(DBI)` at the beginning of your code to load the function.