# Getting error message in R Markdown KNITR

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am getting a very strange issue when using R-Markdown and when I press KNITR.
Each time I run the script I get the error below.

> Error in `read.csv(url("https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/api/v01/dataset/NM_1_1.data.csv?geography=1249902593...1249909543&date=latestMINUS2-latest&sex=7&item=1&measures=20100"))` : 
>     could not find function "read.csv"

This code does not feature in my script and exists in another document that I had created. I have changed the folder directory, cleared the environment. Yet this annoying error keeps appearing when pressing KNITR. I have created a new file, directory everything yet it keeps appearing.

I would be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: could not find function ... in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

Comment: What do you mean "exists in another document that I had created"? Is this code you want to be running, or is this undesired code that is running for some unknown reason? I think if you want any real help, you need to provide a [mcve] of your rmarkdown file that reproduces that error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `read.csv` from `utils` package as shown

```
utils::read.csv(url("https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/api/v01/dataset/NM_1_1.data.csv?geography=1249902593...1249909543&date=latestMINUS2-latest&sex=7&item=1&measures=20100"))
```

or

```
library(utils)
read.csv(url("https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/api/v01/dataset/NM_1_1.data.csv?geography=1249902593...1249909543&date=latestMINUS2-latest&sex=7&item=1&measures=20100"))
```

Comment: Hello Mr Lunalo so will running this code stop the line of code appearing in R Markdown?

Comment: Yes,  What is happening is that the standard packages in r might be loading after your r profile is is processed so you have to call the package again to access the function.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, i am trying that right now. Many thanks.

Comment: Hello Mr Lunalo, I have tried your suggestion by pasting in the above code in the RMarkdown script and i still get the same error.                                       Error in read.csv(url("https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/api/v01/dataset/NM_1_1.data.csv?geography=1249902593...1249909543&date=latestMINUS2-latest&sex=7&item=1&measures=20100")) : 
  could not find function "read.csv"

Comment: As mentioned it seems to be referencing an old link to something in my RMarkdown.

Comment: Hello thank you sir, but unfortunate this code didnt work. But thank you for your suggestion. Regards MD