# md.pattern() does not work after library(mice)

Tags: r, r-mice

I just wanted to learn how to deal with missing value. I found the `mice` package, but if I run `install.package` and `library` R cannot find `md.pattern`. Does anybody know why?

```r
install.packages("mice")
library(mice)

md.pattern(data)
```

> Error in md.pattern(data) : could not find function "md.pattern"

```r
library(mice)
```

> Loading required package: lattice
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘minqa’
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘mice’ was built under R version 3.4.4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: could not find function ... in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

Comment: Can you post  output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: library(mice)
Loading required package: lattice
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘minqa’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘mice’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
md.pattern(iris.mis)
Error in md.pattern(iris.mis) : could not find function "md.pattern"

Comment: I think something goes wrong when I do the library

Answer (score 1):

Search mice from the part where we installed all packages and ☑️mice from the packages .it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Install package minqa first then install mice again.