# Error: could not find function "accuracy"

Tags: r

I want to check accuracy of what i predicted using linear regression.

I'm using R studio and R.

I want to use the accuracy function, however it keeps giving me:

```
Error: could not find function "accuracy"
```

I have done the following:

```
install.packages("forecast")
install.packages("zoo")
library("forecast")
library("zoo")
```

I installed the required packages, but i still get the same result, what is the issue here, and what goes wrong?

Code:

```
install.packages("forecast")
install.packages("zoo")
library("forecast")


   library("zoo")



 linearRegression2 <- lm(formula = Average.Cost.for.two ~ Aggregate.rating, data = avgCostData)
 summary(linearRegression2)
     newData2 <- data.frame(Aggregate.rating = c(3))
     predictAvgCost2 <- predict(linearRegression2, newData2)
     predictAvgCost2
     accuracy(predictAvgCost2,avgCostData)
```

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing the code that throws an error, but you should start with basic [troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/5325862)

Comment: i have edited with the code

Answer (score 1):

Linear regression is regression - not classification. So accuracy as a metric is not possible.