# Error in tbl_df(hflights) : could not find function "tbl_df"

Tags: r

I am facing the following issue 
 please help me out.

> Error in tbl_df(hflights) : could not find function "tbl_df"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: could not find function ... in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

Comment: Did you load `tibble` ie `install.packages("tibble");library(tibble)`?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to load `tibble` package before using the function. If you haven't installed the package yet, you can install and load it using

```
install.packages("tibble")
library(tibble)
```