# Error in lrm(Model1, data = df) : could not find function "lrm" in R

Tags: r, package

Is there a way so solve this? The lrm function was working earlier on, but stoped on one moment. I tried to uninstall the package and then install it again, but the lrm function still didn't work. Restarting R didn't work either. Anyone a solution?

Comment: did you run `library(rms)` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r