# How do I translate in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to compute this in R

[image]

When I tried

```
exp(1)^ln(1.89)/10
```

I get the error: `Error in ln(1.89) : could not find function "ln"`

I was wondering if ln is ^

I tried `exp(1)^(1.89/10)` but I get a value of 1.208041 and the answer should be 1.066.

Am I translating the equation into R correctly?

Comment: Check `?log`, It would be exp(1)^(log(1.89)/10)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

log() is the function you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

```r
T_val <- 2 # some value
exp(log(1.89) / 10 * T_val)
```

You should `log` and not `ln`. Moreover, parenthesis are important due to [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)  (`^` versus `/` and `*`).