# R "Winsorize" cannot be found

Tags: r

I have installed packages "robustHD" and "DescTools", because I want to winsorize my data. Both packages include the option to `winsorize`.
My data is called `eff_tax`
I used the following code to winsorize my data

```
eff_tax_test= winsorize(eff_tax,minval = NULL, maxval = NULL,probs=c(0.01, 0.99))
```

But when I run this code, I get the following ERROR message:

> Error in winsorize(eff_tax, minval = NULL, maxval = NULL, probs = c(0.01,  :
> could not find function "winsorize"

I have no idea, why R doesn't recognize "winsorize".

Comment: Have you loaded the package? That is, did you call `library(robustHD)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r