# alternative coordinates packages

Tags: r, package

I'm a beginner in R and do with that my homework.
I want to change the coordinates of some point to draw my country  weather station like this:

```
stations <- read.csv("Stations.csv")
coordinates(stations)<-~lon+lat
plot(stations)
```

like this image:

[image]

my data are like this:

[image]

but at the first I want to start and install the coordinates package, this error is shown:

**"  package ‘coordinates’ is not available for this version of R   "**

please help meو what can I do?

Comment: (1) Don't share images of data, I won't spend the time to transcribe your data into something usable. (2) `coordinates` is not a package, it's a function, and it is in the `sp` package. Start with `library(sp)`, and if that fails then try `install.packages(sp)` (and then `library(sp)` again).

Comment: I'm guessing that you first encountered the error `could not find function "coordinates"`, in which case this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/3358272. Please reply when you've tried my above steps and whether it works. Thank you!

Comment: yes I was wrong

thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coordinates is not a package, it's a function, and it is in the "sp" package.
Start with library(sp), and if that fails then try install.packages(sp),
and then library(sp)