# Error in shapefile(dataFolder, "file.shp")) : could not find function "shapefile"

Tags: r

I am getting an error, saying could not find the function "shapefile".
I also tried all the possible solutions.
I did the shp, .shx and .dbf files in the same folder and many more but it doesn't work, any help, please?

```
library(raster)
setwd("filename of the folder ")
S <-shapefile(datafolder,"file.shp"))
```

then error

> Error in shapefile(dataFolder, "file.shp")) : could not find function "shapefile"

Comment: Are you sure that `raster` loaded? Did you get any message after the library call?

Comment: may be worth having a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Here I show that/how `raster::shapefile` works.

```
library(raster)
filename <- system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster")
filename
#[1] "C:/soft/R/R-4.1.1/library/raster/external/lux.shp"
p <- shapefile(filename)
p
#class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
#features    : 12 
#extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#variables   : 5
#names       : ID_1,     NAME_1, ID_2,   NAME_2, AREA 
#min values  :    1,   Diekirch,    1, Capellen,   76 
#max values  :    3, Luxembourg,   12,    Wiltz,  312
```

Your

```
S <-shapefile(datafolder,"file.shp"))
```

is not proper R syntax (parenthesis do not match). Perhaps you want

```
S <- shapefile("file.shp")
```

or

```
S <- shapefile(file.path(datafolder,"file.shp"))
```

in which case you do not need to set the working directory