# Problems with "select" in R

Tags: r

I use code:

```
z <- filter(dat, Sex=="M" & Diet=="chow") %>% select(Bodyweight) %>% unlist.
```

And it is written:
Error in select(., Bodyweight) : could not find function "select"

Do you know how to fix it?
This code was written by professors from Harvard.. Probably I have not installed the appropriate package..

Comment: Sounds like you’re missing `dplyr` / `tidyverse`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: could not find function ... in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

Comment: FYI, just in case someone is interested in an alternative, you can do this operation more simply in base R: `z <- dat[dat$Sex == 'M' & dat$Diet == 'chow', 'Bodyweight']`