# Error in R: could not find function "ggpairs"

Tags: r, ggally, ggpairs

rom a tutorial I'm using, the exercise is to run this code below.

```
library(datasets)

data(iris)

View(iris)

library(GGally)

ggpairs(iris, mapping=ggplot2::aes(colour = Species))
```

However, when I run it I get the following error:

```
Error in ggpairs(iris, mapping = ggplot2::aes(colour = Species)) : 
  could not find function "ggpairs"
```

I'm not sure what exactly the problem is and I can't seem to find any similar error solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/680068 , go through the list of possible problems from the linked post.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, R 4.0.2, GGally_2.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only able to reproduce your error if I don't call `library(GGally)`. Since you're calling it, I suspect you haven't installed it yet with `install.packages("GGally")`