# R: Error in kbl(data, ...) : could not find function "kbl"

Tags: r, kable

I have a function to create a quick and basic cable:

```
quick_kable <-function(data, ...){
  
  kbl(data, ...) %>% kable_styling() 
}
```

And whenever I call this function:

```
quick_kable(contents(dat))
```

It returns this error:

```
Error in kbl(data, ...) : could not find function "kbl"
```

I already installed the package `kableExtra`, so I don't know what else I could be doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r

Comment: In addition to installing the package, you need to load it in each session where you want to use it. Use `library(kableExtra)` earlier in your code. Or use `kableExtra::kbl` to be explicit.