# cannot find integrateODE function in r

Tags: r

I would like to preface this question that I am unfamiliar with coding and the language used in it, so I apologize if this question is easily fixed.  I am working on a plot for my master's thesis data, and I modeled a plot years ago, turns out my numbers weren't as accurate as I should've made them, so I am redoing it all in R.  I have these packages added for this: descTools, mosaic, mosaicCalc, mosiaicCore, m osaicData, and plotfun.  I saved all of the lines previously used, and when I copy and paste them into r, I get error messages.  Here is the first line that I am trying:

solG1 = integrateODE(dx~((Fw*(dw-x)-(Forg*D))/M),x=-0.5031328,Fw=25*10^18,dw=-4,Forg=3.12*10^18,D=-28,M=4.1*10^18,tdur=list(from=0,to=0.7222))

this gets me this message:

Error in integrateODE(dx ~ ((Fw * (dw - x) - (Forg * D))/M), x = -0.5031328,  :
could not find function "integrateODE"

any help on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated! I am at a stand still.  I was getting a different error earlier, something about not being able to find the function tdur.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Try to write: `solG1 = mosaic::integrateODE(dx~((Fw*(dw-x)-(ForgD))/M),x=-0.5031328,Fw=2510^18,dw=-4,Forg=3.1210^18,D=-28,M=4.110^18,tdur=list(from=0,to=0.7222))`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  I get this error now.     Error: 'integrateODE' is not an exported object from 'namespace:mosaic'

Comment: Ok. Try `mosaicCalc::integrateODE(dx~((Fw*(dw-x)-(Forg*D))/M),x=-0.5031328,Fw=2510^18,dw=-4,Forg=3.1210^18,D=-28,M=4.110^18, domain(t=0:0.7222))`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/3358272. Closing this as it seems Alex has the correct package (google [`"cran" "integrateODE"`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=cran+integrateode)) and it'll pop up there too).