# How to fix "could not find function "Read10X" "?

Tags: r

```
bmc.data <- Read10X(data.dir = "data/filtered_gene_bc_matrices/hg19")
Error in Read10X(data.dir = "data/filtered_gene_bc_matrices/hg19") : 
  could not find function "Read10X"
(pbmc.data<- Read("/Users/mindeng/Documents/sc-RNAseq analysis/单细胞分析学习-课程/Lepr-分析/mm10"))
Error in Read("/Users/mindeng/Documents/sc-RNAseq analysis/单细胞分析学习-课程/Lepr-分析/mm10") : 
  could not find function "Read"
pbmc.data <- Read10X(data.dir = "data/filtered_gene_bc_matrices/hg19")
Error in Read10X(data.dir = "data/filtered_gene_bc_matrices/hg19") : 
  could not find function "Read10X"
```

How to fix this problem? many thanks!

Comment: Presumably by first running `library(Seurat)` assuming that's the package the function comes from.

Comment: Welcome to SO, min Deng! I expect this will be resolved with https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/3358272; if not, you will need to [edit] your question and explain why that doesn't work (otherwise this question will likely be closed as a duplicate of that). Thanks!