# Can't get a download R-package "tictoc" that appears to be installed to run in R-studio

Tags: r, package, macos-catalina, failed-installation, rstudio-server

Running R- under R-Studio on a Mac, OS Catalina 10.15.7

Downloaded from CRAN the package "tictoc".  It appears to have been installed correctly but on trying to run it (either within a script or from the console window), get the error message "Could not find function 'tic'.

I reverted to using R (rather than R-studio), downloaded and installed the same package, and it runs correctly from the R-console.  So it doesn't appear that there is a download or Mac security.

Expected the function "tic" to run from the R-studio console and in the script (which runs)

Comment: how are you trying to run it?  did you load the package (eg with `library(tictoc)` and was there an error message then?

Comment: Without additional details this is just a duplicate of the [could not find function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r) function. It's usually caused from failure to load the package. There's nothing "special" about this particular package. Please show the exact input/output from your R console where you are trying to use the function.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The tictoc package was in fact correctly downloaded but I need to check the box in the "Install" pulldown menu of R-studio.  It runs as advertised (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tictoc/tictoc.pdf)