# R : could not find function "LGB"

Tags: r

Can anyone help me on this?

I am doing a report for significant effects in unreplicated fractional factorials.
I am using R.

The file name is Soup,

```
    Model.1 <- lm (Yield ~ (.)^2, data = Soup)
    modc <- lm(y~(.)^2, data=soup)
    library(daewr)
    LGB(coef(modc)[-1], rpt = FALSE)
```

This is code that I have been given previously, which worked.

The error message that I get is:

```
    Error in LGB(coef(modc)[-1], rpt = FALSE) : could not find function "LGB"
```

I have installed and loaded the daewr library as noted.
When I search for LGB, I get then following:

[image]

I am using RStudio 2023.03.0 Build 386 and R Version and the latest version of R.

Can anyone advise how to resolve this?
Either I am calling the LGB function incorrectly or there is an issue with it?

If there is a known issue, can an alternative package and library be used instead.

Comment: Have you called `library(daewr)` before trying to use `LGB`? Does trying `daewr::LGB` work for you?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/3358272 for several ways (in addition to the plain `library(daewr)`) for locating functions in various locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very weird situation where the `LGB` function, which is indeed listed in the help pages for the `daewr` package, is not exported by the package.  To use it you need three colons (`:::`), e.g.

```r
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ . - am - gear - carb, mtcars)
daewr:::LGB(coef(m1)[-1], rpt = FALSE)
```

(`LGB` says it's constrained to work only for coefficient vectors of length 7,8,11,15,16,26,31,32,35,63,or 127 (???), so I dropped some of the columns of `mtcars` from the regression).

This seems like a bug in the package. (It's also not clear what `LGB` is really doing, as it seems to be a trivial wrapper for the [also not exported] `LGBc` function ... maybe these are experimental functions?) Maybe worth contacting the maintainer (`maintainer("daewr")`), or asking the person you got the code from?