# Error in R: I am getting an error in R, the VlnPlot function is not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, seurat

Error in R: I am getting an error in R, the VlnPlot function is not found, while trying to make the plot. Also, several other plot like feature scatter and others are also throwing the error not found.

[Here is the error that i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUrY9.png)

Comment: Could you please share the code you have tried including the packages?

Comment: check if the seurat package is installed, and check if `library(seurat)` works.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/680068