# Error in displaying plots loaded from .RData file

Tags: r, save

I created some plots using ggcorrplot and saved them to a list in RStudio

When I try to view the plots using list$correplot it works

The next step is to save the list using the save function in R and load it inside a UI

When I try to view the plot in the UI, it gives the error

```
`Error in continuous_range() : could not find function "continuous_range"`
```

Can anyone let me know the reason for the error. It looks like there is some error in the save function

Comment: You've got `ggplot2` loaded, right?

Comment: This question is almost certainly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/3358272, which should pop up when searching with the literal error of your code.

Comment: @r2evans good comments. I haven't seen the prev question(s), but I should've checked for duplicate too.

Comment: I think `continuous_range` is a ggproto function from `ggplot2` based on https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggplot2-ggproto.html. Since `library(ggplot2); gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point(); saveRDS(gg, "gg.rds")` in one R session and `gg <- readRDS("~/Downloads/gg.rds"); print(gg)` (without `library(ggplot2)`) in a new R session does not reproduce your issue here, then there is very little we can do without knowing how you formed the object that you saved. Whether or not this is a dupe of my previous link, it is still not reproducible.