# Error in select(df.clean, gender, treatment) : could not find function "select"

Tags: r

I have encountered error in finding function "select" and how to install the gt packages in the R programming language. I am unable to visualize the intersections of the variables. Are gt packages and gt summary packages similar?

Comment: Hi Aakansha, welcome to SO. Have you loaded the package that contains `select`? I think it is usually in tidyverse, so you would want to have `library(tidyverse)` in your script before using `select()`. If you can edit your post to include the full script you have written, we can provide better advice/answers.

Comment: Though @JayBee is correct, to be more specific, `select()` is from the `dplyr` package within `tidyverse`. You should call `library(dplyr)` before using select.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: could not find function ... in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

`gt` and `gtsummary` are both packages. I doubt that the `select` function is in either one but as a commenter suggested you need to execute:

```
library(tidyverse)# actually many packages
```

That will almost surely load a package that has `select`. The `gtsummary` has a lot of packages that are required, including `gt`. You can see the full list at: https://cran.r-project.org/package=gtsummary .  It’s possible that you will get an error message about further missing packages that are not in the tidyverse collection. Keep installing all missing packages and the try reinstalling `gtsummary` until you get success.

Answer (score 2):

You may have loaded a package that conflicts with dplyr's `select`. Assuming you wish to use dplyr's select, you may explicitly refer to dplyr's select via `dplyr::select`.

Comment: I suspect that the OP will need more than just `dplyr` if she want to install `gt` and/or `gtsummary`.